# Is the transpose of the projection under the exponentiation adjunction a constant morphism?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, adjoint-functors

Consider a cartesian closed category $\mathbf{C}$ and fix an object $B \in \mathbf{C}$.

For any $X$, we have the product $X \times B$ and a projection $\pi_B : X \times B \rightarrow B$.
Under the exponential adjunction $- \times B \dashv (-)^B$, this map $\pi_B$ corresponds to its transpose $\overline{\pi_B} : X \rightarrow B^B$.

In $\mathbf{Set}$, it's immediately clear that this is the constant map picking out the the identity on $B$ for every element of $X$.
I expect that this generalizes in the sense that $\overline{\pi_B}$ should always be a constant morphism (i.e., a morphism factoring through the terminal object).

I've played around this this a bit, but I'm unsure how to prove it.
If it were the case that $\pi_B$ factored as $\pi_B = X \times B \xrightarrow{\bot_X \times B} 1 \times B \xrightarrow{\phi} B$, where $\bot_X$ is the unique map $X \rightarrow 1$ and $\phi$ is an isomorphism between $1 \times B$ and $B$, then the result would follow by taking the transpose of both sides yielding $\overline{\pi_B} = X \xrightarrow{\bot_X} 1 \xrightarrow{\overline{\phi}} B^B$, but I'm not seeing why such a factorization would exist, or if this approach is the right one.

Comment: Look at the naturality of $\pi_B$.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean use the universal property of the product and projections, then yes, $1 \leftarrow X \times B \rightarrow B$ is a cone over $(1, B)$ so there is a unique map $\gamma : X \times B \rightarrow 1 \times B$ with $\pi = \phi \circ \gamma$. But the map $X \times B \rightarrow 1 \times B$ could be seemingly *anything*, but I need it to be the functor $- \times B$ applied to some map (i.e. $\bot_X \times B$) in order to apply the naturality rule for transpose of compositions. I do not see why this unique map $\gamma$ should be *this* map.

Comment: $\pi_B$ is a natural transformation. (Why?) In particular, it is a natural transformation $-\times B\to\Delta B$ where $\Delta B$ is the constantly $B$ functor, i.e. $\Delta B(X)=B$ and $\Delta B(f)=id_B$. What does the naturality square look like in this case? $\phi=\pi_B$ when $X=1$. (Prove this.) There's then a naturality square for the arrow $X\to 1$. What does it say?

Comment: I should have said you can choose $\phi=\pi_B$. There isn't that much flexibility in what $\phi$ can be, though, particularly if we also require it to be natural in $B$.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{AMScd}$Your factorization of $\pi_B $ can be proved by considering the following commutative diagram of pullback squares:
\begin{CD}
X\times B @>>> 1\times B @>>> B\\
@VVV@VVV@VVV\\
X@>>>1@=1
\end{CD}
By pullback pasting, the outer rectangle is a pullback as well, hence the top row is $\pi_B $.